# Not able to open browser from Azure cloud shell

Tags: azure, azure-cloud-shell

I trying to open a browser from cloud shell. I have firefox installed in cloud shell but can't launch it.

getting this error :

> XPCOMGlueLoad error for file ...../firefox/libxul.so:
>   libgtk-x11-2.0.so.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
>   Couldn't load XPCOM.

I found a couple of solutions on Google but didn't work. So thought of checking if it's allowed to launch a browser from Azure cloud Shell or not?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably, It's not allowed to do that since cloud shell offers a browser-accessible, **pre-configured shell experience** for managing Azure resources without the overhead of installing, versioning, and maintaining a machine yourself.

You could get more details about [Features & tools for Azure Cloud Shell](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cloud-shell/features).

Answer (score 0):

No, this is not possible, because its a guiless container. so there is no video in the container. you can only use tty